# One-to-many relationships with code-first Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to set up a one-to-many relationship (I think) using code-first Entity Framework.

I have a `ProductListing` object which can have many associated `Country` objects. I had thought that I had set this up correctly, but my `Countries` table has a reference column for `ProductListing`. This is a problem because although a `ProductListing` can have a relationship with `Country`, the `Country` object should not be aware or reliant upon the `ProductListing` object.

**ProductListing**

```
public class ProductListing : AuditedEntity<long>
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public long RetailerId { get; set; }
    public Retailers.Retailer Retailer { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Countries.Country> Countries { get; set; }

    public bool IsOfficial { get; set; }

    public decimal CurrentPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal PreviousPrice { get; set; }

    public string ListingUrl { get; set; }
    public string AffiliateString { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShipDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpiresDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Country**

```
public class Country : AuditedEntity<long>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(ShylockConsts.MaxNameLength)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(ShylockConsts.MaxIsoLength)]
    public virtual string IsoCode { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually have is a `many-to-many` relationship where a Product can have many Countries, and a Country can have many Products.

To model this, you will need an intermediate joining table to hold the Countries for each Product.

Eg.

```
public class ProductCountry
{
    [Required]
    public virtual long ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual long CountryID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And then the Country and ProductListing objects will have an ICollection<ProductCountry> property?

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much @Steve. Coming from a web forms and raw ADO.NET I'm enjoying the robustness of these frameworks. Just have a hard time with the conventions every now and again.

Comment: I have a question @Steve; a `Country` doesn't really have any relationship with a `ProductListing`. Whilst a `ProductListing` can have many Countries, a `Country` doesn't _own_ a `ProductListing`.

Comment: @MrBearding that's true, but all the `ICollection` is is a navigation property, which allows you to see the referenced entities from that entity.

Comment: Okay, so from a real-world perspective, the Country is decoupled from ProductListing, but from an application perspective, there is a relationship there; *ProductListings have a country*

Answer (score 1):

Add a collection nav property to the `Country` entity as well to model a many-to-many relationship as @Steve said (but there is no need to create an entity for the junction table in the conceptual model)

```
public class ProductList : ...
{
    public ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public class Country : ...
{
    public ICollection<ProductListing> ProductListings { get; set; }
}
```